# Function access to surrounding object's variable

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2

```
var CreateFeature = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {


    clazz : "xyz",

    set_item : function(e) {


        var position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
        var latitude = position.lat;
        var longitude = position.lon;

        var marker = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(longitude, latitude), {
            draggable : true,
            clazz : this.clazz, /** this one should be set to 'abc' **/
        }, items_symbolizer);

        layer_items.addFeatures([marker]);
        marker.state = OpenLayers.State.INSERT;

    });


var br = new CreateFeature(layer_items, {
        clazz : "abc",
        title : "Create Feature",
    });
```

I want to create an Object with a function parameter that has access to a variable of the object's scope. However, `this.clazz` remains undefined. Any ideas?

I am looking for a way to either set `this.clazz` to 'abc' or to 'xyz'.